# Racial discrimination at Duke University's Biostatistics department

Tags: united-states, international-students, law

The director of graduate studies at Duke's Biostatistics department has stepped down after her racially discriminatory emails, targeted at their international Chinese master's students, went viral on the Internet.

How can an affected Chinese student in the program proceed with their semester safely, without facing retaliation?

They have been threatened with no research opportunities and other possible impediments to their job search, for speaking Chinese loudly in the student lounge and in other areas outside of class time; namely, while I can appreciate the support for the director and distinguishing between her good intentions and unintended discrimination in her email messages to the students, the threats of retaliation by a couple of professors are problematic, e.g. these professors asked the director for photos of the Chinese students and were subsequently targeting them with no research projects.

Comment: Is this hypothetical, or are you one of the students affected? Are you looking for a general answer or something actionable?

Comment: this question right now lacks specifics, so answers will probably be very general ("talk to the dean"). You should add what is the problem, and what you want to happen

Comment: What I don't understand here is who threatened the students? The director of graduate studies who has stepped down? If so, who would retaliate? Has somebody else threatened the student for speaking Chinese, and acted discriminatory after the director has stepped down for that same reason? If so (and if the University is already dealing with discriminatory elements), why not deal with this incident the same way the director of graduate studies has been dealt with, i.e. notifying the proper authorities (dean, or similar?) to the discriminatory behaviour?

Comment: Let me give a little more insight as someone who is at Duke- 1. the graduate students were not in the lounge but in the community kitchen. 2. They were being loud during the working day. 3. Megan had to be the bearer of bad news for annoyed faculty who wanted them to respect the working space. Should Megan have made an insinuation about research? Resoundingly no. She should have just told them to clear out. I dont see why they were there. There are a TON of communal spaces in the med center where they could have been without disturbing faculty.

Comment: @JWH2006 I think you've completely missed the point. The issue is not that a faculty member asked students to be quiet, the point is that they asked them to not speak Chinese and insinuated that continuing to speak Chinese on their own time rather than English would come with consequences. The clear emphasis in the email was that Chinese language was the problem, not loud conversation. "*To international students, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE keep these unintended consequences in mind when you choose to speak in Chinese in the building.*"

Comment: @BryanKrause I still don't follow who is currently threatening the students, and who might retaliate against them. A faculty member did something discriminatory. That faculty member stepped down as a consequence. If the question is saying that the students fear retribution from the rest of the faculty, or that the rest of the faculty has blamed them for director stepping down, I would understand the question. Like this, it seems like the students are in an environment which actively deals with discrimination - hence the director stepping down - and therefore I can't understand their fears?

Comment: @penelope I agree, that's partly why I voted to close the question.

Comment: @penelope Reading an article about the incident, it says that there were also other faculties involved (investigations seem under way). So probably the discrimination is not so isolated.

Comment: @BryanKrause What discrimination is going on at Duke? The whole triangle area is extremely cosmopolitan. I think this question would be better served if there was some articulation on the exact concerns that the poster has? A large portion of the biostats faculty IS Chinese (and very talented at that, the paper with the largest impact published last year was from a Chinese faculty member). Where is this person feeling unsafe and what resources available have been exhausted (e.g. the ASA here on campus)?

Comment: @JWH2006 Have you read the email sent by the former head of the program? That demonstrates the (blatant) discrimination. Blatant enough that the person responsible for the email immediately resigned that position. I think overall the biostats department handled it just fine from my outsider perspective, but unless Neely misstated the positions of her colleagues there were multiple people in the department with these views.

Comment: @BryanKrause I read the email and I know of the underlying situation that led up to that email being sent. I listened to the president's response to it as well. I also heard the support for Megan from the Chinese graduate community in the stats/biostats departments. Megan isnt tenure track so I imagine her contract will not be up for renewal.  That said, I also know about the work she has done to help connect the Chinese masters students with the tech industry here in the triangle. I think reading the student testimonials from Chinese students in support of Megan might change your view.

Comment: @JWH2006 I can appreciate the support for Megan and you distinguishing between intentions and unintended discrimination in her message to the students.  However, the *threats* of retaliation are problematic, e.g. the professors asking Megan for photos of the Chinese students and then targeting them with no research projects, for example.

Comment: @user103955 The situation you describe in your last comment adds a lot to the question, and gives a concrete context to your question and explains why the students in question feel threatened. If you edited that into your question (and/or any other example of actions following the directors resignation that have been similarly threatening and problematic), we could consider reopening it since we could give more targeted responses.

Comment: @user103955 Am I correct in my understanding that these professors asked for photos (bad, bad thing) of the director _after_ she had already resigned due to her racially discriminatory e-mails (making it even worse), and she actually _provided_ them after already facing consequences of her discriminatory actions? (terrible thing bordering idiotic with self-destructive tendencies).

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 8):

I believe that for the students the situation has resolved itself. But I expect that it was collective action on the student's part that brought it to the attention of higher powers. I might be wrong in all of this, of course, but I think that people have been made sensitive to the problem and will be less willing to engage in (blatant) discrimination.

So, it may be that in the short term, things will improve.

But in general, it is collective action that is needed to bring such things to the fore. Bad things can happen in dark alleys. The light of day is a good disinfectant. But when someone powerful is acting badly, individual action might only make it worse for the individual. There is power in numbers.

If the students are still threatened, it is good to stick together.

Individuals can, of course, seek reassurance from their professors. If it isn't forthcoming, more light is needed.

Comment: "If the students are still threatened, it is good to stick together."  This might be interpreted as "Only interact with people of your own race." which is bad advice.  I think you intended "work as a group to address racism."  My (limited) understanding of Chinese culture is that working as a group is customary.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, actually, I think most students, whatever their race, would be appalled by such behavior of a Dean. And collective action should, in general, be as wide as possible.

Answer (score -1):

If these students believe that there existing/prior/future opportunities and outcomes have/will been adversely affected by racial discrimination that falls afoul of university policy or discrimination law, the best thing to do would be to put in a formal complaint to the university to this effect and seek an appropriate remedy (e.g., being granted the missed opportunities at issue).

One of the benefits of a formal complaint is that it almost always triggers non-retaliation requirements so long as the complaint is a *bona fide* one.  If retaliation were to occur then this should be pursued with another formal complaint, and so on.  Of course, there is never a guarantee that people will not retaliate in defiance of policy/law, but having put in a formal complaint puts the students in a position of strength against such action.  As in all cases where a person is considering formal complaint proceedings, it is important to document relevant events, gather relevant evidence, and collate it in a clear way.